# Baking Normals Problem in Blender 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, baking, normal-map

I've tried many things to try and get this to work. (ALT+G, Recalculation outside and inside normals, using a cage, flipping the normals on both meshes, and changing the extrusion size) I still get artifacts.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GgjGtBGsBlDtNQBkTmqcvZyDUi4ietkn)

I think it renders on the mesh properly. but based off the actual image, I think something is not right.
[image: Normal Map]
[image: (Left to Right)Cage, High-poly, Low-poly]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I had to disconnect the Image texture in the shader editor. I really don't know why this caused a problem...